# Eclipse doesn't show which classes were changed anymore

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using the Kleper version of Eclipse. Days ago the IDE was working fine but I made some configurations in Window -> Preferences and my Eclipse doesn't show anymore which classes were changed.

When I say "classes were changed" I mean the symbol '>' beside the class name is gone. Example: > Teste.java

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Do you use a version controll system? If yes, which one? Is the project checked in? Have you tried an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you accidently changed a setting in `General->Appearance->Label Decorations`? There you can enable/disable annotations ... e.g. `CVS` anntotations.

Comment: You are right. I clicked on Restore Defaults Button and this action made unchecked the CVS option

Answer (score 1):

It depends of your versioning system, but in general this is set in :

Window -> Preference -> Team -> your_version_system -> Label Decoration

in the Text Decorations tab.